# Laravel project not showing me index.php

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5, wamp, vhosts

I'm using Win10 with WAMP server.
I installed wamp and created my virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/project/public"
    ServerName project
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/project/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then i used Composer + git  to get back  a project (laravel), but when I try to access to my project  it shows me the folders Inside public and not the index.php

Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.cs>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Option -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

      RewriteEngine On


      # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A folder...
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If its not executing PHP, check your WAMP installation. Also,check php-mcrypt extension is installed and active.In the Virtual host i use the below configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName homestead.app
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/project/public"
<Directory  "c:/wamp/www/project/public">
Require all granted
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Where homestead.app is your name and add it to the host file

Comment: Php is executed ( php -v answer PHP5.5.12). For the php-mcrypt extension couldn't find anything in php.ini
The host has already been added to hosts file in system32